# Matching Values from Separate Sheet - Need Tweak to Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We just need a little help refining a formula used to match values from a separate sheet (SHEET2) with those in our MAIN sheet. We have something that is close to working as follows:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,SHEET2!$A$1:$I$380,1,0),"")
```

This adds a numerical value found in column 1 of SHEET2 to a column in our MAIN sheet if the value is found in the 'D' column of our MAIN sheet. This works properly if there is only a single number in the D column (e.g, 2222). But some of the rows in our MAIN sheet have multiple numbers listed (e.g, '2222, 2223, 2224, 2227').

- How would we modify the formula to add the value if it matches ANY of the numbers listed in column D (which are always a comma-delimited list when they appear)?
- If there are multiple matches for a single row (e.g., if it matched both 2222 and 2224), we would want both values to be added.

SAMPLE DATA 
(Col. E on MAIN sheet is one we're filling based on Col. A on SHEET2)

MAIN SHEET:

```
    | - | A       | B               | C        | D                | E          |
    | 1 | Name    | Email           | Phone    | Customer ID      | Promotion  | 
    | 2 | Joe S.  | joes@email.com  | 555-1212 | 2200             | 2200       | 
    | 3 | Sue M.  | suem@email.com  | 555-1212 | 2232             |            | 
    | 4 | Fred J. | fredj@email.com | 555-1212 | 2222, 2223, 2224 | 2222, 2224 | 
    | 5 | Mary E. | marye@email.com | 555-1212 | 2224             | 2224       |
```

SHEET2 (only unique single numbers per row in Col. A):

```
| A        | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| Promo ID | Other unimportant data...
| 2200     |
| 2222     |
| 2224     |
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post some sample data

Comment: Will need sample data to confirm, but I don't think you can do what you are trying to do with a VLOOKUP

Comment: Added some basic sample data. Real data has more columns and about 3,000 rows in MAIN, and about 350 rows in SHEET2.

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS())

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(SHEET2!$A:$A,SHEET2!$A:$A,TRIM(FILTERXML("<A><B>"&SUBSTITUTE(D2,",","</B><B>")&"</B></A>","//B"))))
```

[image]

Comment: I've never seen filterxml before and now i've seen it twice today lol

Comment: I just finally feel like I know how to use it myself.  Got tired of @RonRosenfeld scooping my points. :)

Comment: Tried to find examples online but documentation/easy to follow examples are not so good. Still have no idea what is happening here ha

Comment: @urdearboy it creates an xml string: `<A><B>2222</B><B> 2223</B><B> 2224</B><B> 2227</B></A>` and the `"//B"` tells the filter we want all the parts between `<B>` and `</B>`.  The FILTERXML returns those as an array.

Comment: WOW - great explanation. I wish I could upvote twice sometimes

Comment: Tried your formula, but get error stating 'Formula refers to empty cells'. Not sure which to alter here. Added some sample data to my question. Plus, the example you show appears to be adding the 2 numbers together in Col. C (guessing that's what SUMPRODUCT does?!?). I would want both displayed (e.g,. 2222, 2224).